# How can we add contact with custom fields to a contact list programmatically in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-forms, contact-facets

I want to use sitecore 9.3 form for creating a new contact in a contact list.
The contact list should consist of below custom fields:
Email Id,
Mobile number,
Full Name

The values of these fields should be taken from sitecore forms

This is the form:
[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Don't add 2 questions in 1 post. Split your post in 2, each with 1 question

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create a custom Submit action that will let you pick you form fields and update xConnect fields on the contact.

I don't want a link only answer, but Sitecore already wrote most of the code in their walkthrough.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html

Then in the submit action, you get to pick your forms fields and align it with an xConnect to populate.

[image]

Comment: I have gone through the doc.
In the section "Add a folder that contains parameters for the editor"
There is a table with column headers; FormDropList, Parameter, ValueFieldName, DisplayFieldName, FormLabel, BindingConfiguration


I wanted to know what should be the value of the columns.
Can you help me understand taking the example of "FirstName"

Comment: It is just telling you what stuff to enter in the Sitecore item. https://www.dropbox.com/s/phr0c8ktc59oz8u/2020-09-25_09-40-48.png?dl=0 Its in the core database  /sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/Actions

Comment: FirstName is going to make the First Name in your form to the First Name in xConnect. Do the example as is, when it works and you understand it, you can add your own custom properties. We use this all the time.

Comment: I have followed the same, but after submitting the form I am getting "Update contact failed!" message which is the error message of form submit action
I have deployed the code and js file to sitecore website
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8th0o8vauao9dyi/UpdateFormSubmit.PNG?dl=0

These are the details of my submit action https://www.dropbox.com/s/asbjz5940vlsulc/FormsSubmitActions.PNG?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7f7eqpxpik52ym/UpdateContactSubmit.PNG?dl=0

What could be the possible error?